# What is the difference between VOImpl and VORowImpl?

Tags: oracle-adf

What is the difference between VOImpl and VORowImpl in Oracle ADF?
What is the difference between VOImpl and VORowImpl in Oracle ADF?

Answer (score 2):

The VOImpl represents all rows that are queried by the VO.
The ViewRowImpl represents ONE row from the set represented by the VOImpl.